# Generate random floats from random bytes without bit-twiddling

Tags: random, floating-point

Assuming I have a good-enough(tm) stream of random byte values, is there a mathematical way to convert these into (0 < n < 1) floating-point values that does not need to know the internal format of the floats?

I'm looking for something that:

- Doesn't require bitwise operations (on the floats), and
- Is an iterative process that we can *know* will give a good value after n iterations, where n is a function of the output precision.
- A general process that can be used for floats of any precision, by simply changing the number of iterations, ie consuming more input bytes to generate a double than a single-precision float.

The naive solution is to just build yourself a big integer from a few bytes, and then simply convert to float divide by 2^n, but I can't see how to do it without messing up the distribution.

Another idea is something like this (pseudocode):

```
state := 0.0
n := requiredIterations(outputPrecision)
for(1..n)
    nextByte := getRandomByte()
    state := state + nextByte
    state := state / 256
end
return state
```

It seems like this should work, but I don't know how to prove it :)

Comment: What distribution are you trying to achieve? Uniform in [0,1)? Or are you trying to produce the same number of random numbers per binade? How important is it to be able to hit each possible floating-point number in [0,1)?

Comment: How does "Another idea" differ from building a big integer and dividing it? It looks to me as though you are just doing the power of two division piecemeal as you combine the bytes.

Comment: What do you mean "messing up the distribution"? Combining say 4 bytes into 4-byte entity seems to be sure way to get so-called generator

Comment: By "messing up the distribution" I mean where an even distribution of n-bit integer values will map to an uneven distribution of m-bit floats, whenever m and n are different, simply because you certain destination values will be over / underrepresented in the source space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I think I've got what you need

let's consider sampling float in the range [0...1) in the following way. 256 is 2^8 which is equivalent to next byte shift. Lets combine bytes as

```
b0*256*256*256 + b1*256*256 + b2*256 + b3
```

To get number in [0...1) range you have to divide it by 256*256*256*256, thus

```
f = b0/256 + b1/(256*256) + b2/(256*256*256) + b3/(256*256*256*256)
```

which, in turn, is equivalent to Horner scheme of polynomials computation

```
f = (1/256)*(b0 + (1/256)*(b1 + (1/256)*(b2 + (1/256)*b3)))
```

which, in turn, pretty much what you wrote (for some abstract N)

Answer (score -1):

As Severin Pappadeux says, why not just do something like

```
const double factor = 2.32830643653869628906e-10;    // 2^(-32)
unsigned int accumulator = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
{
    accumulator <<= 8;
    accumulator |= getRandomByte();
}
double r = factor * accumulator;
```